# Custom drawing on top of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, draw

I have some problems drawing some custom content over a UITableView.
What I did was subclass UITableView and overwrite the -(void)drawRect method something like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 255, 0, 0, 1.0f); 
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10));
}
```

The problem is that i see my red rectangle but it's underneath the table view cells.
Even if I comment the [super drawRect:rect] call in the method above, the cells will still display.

My guess is that internally whoever calls the drawRect method for the tableview, draws the cells afterwards, meaning the overwriting drawRect is not enough because the cells will always be drawn afterwards.

Comment: Maybe, you should get `CGContextRef` after `[super drawRect:rect];`?

Comment: Hi, wondering why you would subclass UITableView, especially overriding the drawRect method. The tableView is very customizable.

Comment: @kpower - It's not working. Besides, as i said, if I remove completely the [super drawRect:rect] call, my cells are still drawing.

@RickiG
I want to add a snap feature to the UITableView. The table has a "marker" somewhere and after you drag the table and release the finger the table will automatically align the marker with the nearest cell (simply put, i'm making a horizontal picker).

I need the foreground image to paint the snap "marker".

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that this overriding drawRect for a subclass of UIScrollView works perfectly.
What I like about UITableView is that it comes with the nice lazy request mechanism for each cell and the queue/dequeue system.

Comment: I stand corrected :(. It doesn't work either for UIScrollView.
What appeared to be worked was just some match of colors that created the illusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the image to cover the tableview.  Add an UIImageView as a subview to the view instead.

One can create a frame for your new UIImageView and specify the x/y coordinates as well.

```
[self.view addSubView:myView];
```